# python how to handle http request and response

Tags: python, web-applications, python-3.x, httpresponse

I have two questions. I am new to python and not fluent enough with all the BIF's in python.

I am developing a website database is on amazon simple db.
I am handling all database related queries and code using python scripts.
My first question is given an HTML page where the user gives his his login credentials I call in a python script using my handler javascript function send in a post request and get a response from my python script.
I can send a post request all right and get the values from sdb for validation. What I need to know is how to send in a response from my script back to my html page which could react to the information given.

My second question is how do I maintain an HTTP session using python?

My python code is given below although it shouldn't make for much since no response code is added:

```
      form=cgi.FieldStorage()
      organisationID= form['orgID'].value
      username= form['username'].value
      password= form['password'].value
      sdb=sdbhelper.connect()
      connection= sdb.get_domain('AdminTable')
      itemnames=''
      flag=False
      for item in connection:
             if (item.name==username+'$'+organisationID):
                   retrieved_item=connection.get_item(item.name)
                   if(retrieved_item['Password']==password):
                   flag=True
      #Now Id like to respond with flag so that login validation can be done
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am correctly getting your question what you want to do is to create a small API , Where you send some information to a webpage and get some other .
What you can do is once the user is authenticated you should return it a access key that is valid for a short time period .
One of the way to send data could be inform of JSON objects .
For example if user is  authenticated then return

{

```
 'KEY'         : 'dklsfeir5rufui435uejhfjh5ewh5rf'
```

}

From the next request you can associate this short lived key along the url for access .For example send the next request to abc.py?key=dklsfeir5rufui435uejhfjh5ewh5rf (by get or by post ) . If the key is valid then process the request else send a json response saying error occurred .

The main advantage of using JSON is it can be easily decoded/ encoded for communication 
(JSON | http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html )
Secondly as you have generated access key you would not require any session .